# What is the condition for roots of conjugate reciprocal polynomials to be on the unit circle?

Tags: polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

Given an Nth order complex polynomial $P(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N a_nz^n$ such that $a_n = a^*_{N-n}$ i.e. conjugate reciprocal, [Lakatos and Losonczi](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/230842669_Self-inversive_polynomials_whose_zeros_are_on_the_unit_circle/file/32bfe50e95022b4e58.pdf) mention that a necessary and sufficient condition for all roots of $P(z)$ to be on the unit circle is that all zeros of $P'(z)$ lie on $|z|<1$.

Also they showed that if

$|a_N| \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}|a_n|$,

$P(z)$ has all roots on unit circle.

I'm unable to see how this condition holds when all coefficients $a_n = 1$ or $|a_n| = 1$ i.e. uni-modular coefficients and conjugate reciprocal.

Please help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think it's just a sufficient condition.  There are probably many polynomials which do not satisfy $|a_N| \geq \frac{1}{2} \sum |a_n|$ but which have zeros on the unit circle.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I think you are correct. The condition mentioned above is merely a sufficient condition.